# undefined type name in polymorphic datatype in isabelle

Tags: isabelle

I'm a beginner on Isabelle reading [Programming and Proving in Isabelle/HOL](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/prog-prove.pdf) and I wrote such codes:

```
datatype 'a tree = Tip | Node "'a tree" 'a "'a tree"

value "(Node Tip 3 Tip)::nat tree"    (* 1 *)
value "Node Tip 3::nat Tip"           (* 2 *)
value "Node Tip 3::nat Tip::nat tree" (* 3 *)
```

`(* 1 *)` works but both of the other two outputs `Undefined type name: "Tip"⌂`.

My question is: what is going on and where should I reference to? I tried to search for the answer but actually I don't know what and where to search :(

Thanks!

---

Thanks @Javier Díaz for the answer! Without the parentheses, `value "Node Tip 3::nat Tip"` would be parsed as `value "Node Tip 3::(nat Tip)"`, that's why `"Tip"` is considered as a *type name*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to enclose your type annotations with parentheses as follows:

```
value "(Node Tip 3 Tip)::nat tree"      (* 1 *)
value "Node Tip (3::nat) Tip"           (* 2 *)
value "Node Tip (3::nat) Tip::nat tree" (* 3 *)
```

Note, however, that parentheses are not needed in the first example and that the double type annotation in the third example is superfluous.

As a reference, you may want to read page 191 in the [Isabelle/Isar Reference Manual](https://isabelle.in.tum.de/dist/Isabelle2021-1/doc/isar-ref.pdf).

Comment: @XuanInsr: You're totally correct regarding your last comment. That is a direct consequence of the following paragraph in page 191: "_In idts, note that x :: nat y is parsed as x :: (nat y), treating y like a type constructor applied to nat. To avoid this interpretation, write (x :: nat) y with explicit parentheses._".